change the startuptype of a service that is a cluster resource
I am in powershell and can list services
$resources = get-cluster -name $ClusterName|get-clusterresource | ?{$_resourceType -eq "Generic Service"}

I now need to connect to the actual service on each node in the cluster and change the startuptype.
In the cluster resource manager I can see the service name in the ui, but cannot seem to get that from $Resources
How do I get the Service Name from $Resources?  I am able to manage the service from this point, but need to find a way to link the resource to a service.
Thanks

Is the service name you want a member of the output from Get-Cluster -Name $ClusterName | Get-ClusterResource | Get-Member? Are you using Invoke-Command to connect to the cluster hosts?
